# Problems getting Android Studio to build and install project on Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, android-studio

When I go to install the packages from with Android Studio I get a "ADB not responding" error with wait/restart/close options.

I can run adb from a term. I can see my device and install the apk from the cmd line, but it doesn't work from within Android Studio.

In the terminal (that is running Android Studio) I get the following

```
03:56:36 E/adb: Unexpected exception 'Cannot run program "/media/5b317046-147a-42ee-aec1-f73caf1922c5/home/kloud9/WorkSpace/downloads/workspace/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=13, Permission denied' while attempting to get adb version from '/media/5b317046-147a-42ee-aec1-f73caf1922c5/home/kloud9/WorkSpace/downloads/workspace/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools/adb'
```

I have tried running Android Studio as sudo, but that doesn't help. I have all the environment variables set correctly, I am running oracle sun java jdk1.7.0. Any thoughts on what to try next?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: do `which adb` to see if the adb binary you can successfully run from the term is the same as one used by the studio. also provide output of `ls -l /media/5b317046-147a-42ee-aec1-f73caf1922c5/home/kloud9/WorkSpace/downloads/workspace/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools/adb`

Comment: which adb shows /usr/local/sbin/adb ... which might not be the same adb used by android studio

-rw-r--r-- 1 kloud9 kloud9 1226659 May 13 12:31 /media/5b317046-147a-42ee-aec1-f73caf1922c5/home/kloud9/WorkSpace/downloads/workspace/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools/adb

oh, it's not executable, haha

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, thanks. I wish I would have asked this question like five hours ago ... oh well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This fixed it for me.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```